# Apache Helix Resource Balancer (case: each resource on independent node)

Tags: java, apache, cluster-computing, load-balancing, helix

We're using Apache Helix for our cluster management.  We would like helix to assign the active resource i.e. the Leader of LeaderStandby to an instance which isn't currently holding any active Resources.

E.g. if there are 3 (a, b, c) instances/nodes:
2 instances (a and b) have a resource each with state 'Leader' where as the third (c) has no resource assigned to it. If a new resource is added to the cluster, 'c' should be assigned the new resource.

In this example, I am assuming each resource has only 1 replica, but regardless, if possible, the balancer would ensure that each instance would have max(1) resource in active state (e.g. Leader, Online etc.)

Is there a way to implement this? We would obviously not like to specify which exact node the resource gets assigned to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can consolidate your resources into multiple "partitions" on a single resource. Each partition will have a leader, and by default, FULL_AUTO mode will automatically ensure that leaders for each partition are evenly assigned among the nodes.